# What could be an appropriate word in between long-lived event and short-lived event?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, expression-choice

I am wondering a word to express the moderated values between long-lived and short-lived events. For example, I would like to describe heat wave durations. My durations are 1hr, 2hr, 3hr, .., 10hr. I expressed the durations of heat waves > 8hrs as long-lived events and 1-4hrs as short-lived events. I can't find a appropiated word to express 5-7hr events. Though moderated events sounds nice, but it is missing the live portion.

Comment: I don't think an event can be long-lived or short-lived in the first place. It can be long or short. But not long-lived. That makes no sense. Long, short, and then medium or any synonym offered by a thesaurus of your liking.

Comment: You may be right @RegDwigнt. But many research papers have used such words in this context, thinking that the events last for few hours and then disapears.

Comment: The problem is that long- and short-lived are idiomatic phrases with a long history. The nearest I can suggest is "medium-lived."  The word 'moderated' doesn't fit at all. It sounds as though you are controlling the event.

Comment: Hi @Kayan and welcome to ELU. I think you would probably be better off using short-term, medium-term and long-term events. You will find definitions for these words in online dictionaries.

Comment: Or short/medium/long *duration*.

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions and answers. All the answers look fine for me, but as I was looking for a word with "live" term, so I finally used the "medium-lived" events as suggested @chaslyfromUK .. At present I can't vote up to any answer/ suggestion, because it needs minimum 15 reputations.

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps use *mid-lengthed* or *medium-lengthed* event.

Comment: Too little for editing, but it should be _mid-length_  or _medium-length_...

Answer (score 1):

I proffer - [**Intermediate** (*events*)](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/intermediate)

> The word intermediate comes from the Latin intermediatus, tracing back
> to ***intermedius***, which combines inter-, meaning “between” and medius,
> meaning “middle.” So you can see that intermediate describes something
> or someone in the middle, ***between two distinct phases***.

(vocabulary.com)